# npm basics clarification: differences between npm start and npm build

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

Hi I need some clarification on npm materials.

1. What are the differences between "npm start" and "npm build"?
2. When do we use "run" for example, what are the differences between "npm test" and "npm run test"?

Thank you so much! I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

What you are finding is that there are some default scripts in NPM. Some of these are:

- `npm start`
- `npm build`
- `npm test`

These are simply just aliases for `npm run xxxx`. To answer your question, `npm run test` and `npm test` are exactly the same. `npm test` is just a shorthand alias.

These default scripts are there to be used as kind of "universal" commands. For example: you have two different projects that have two different build processes. However, you could run `npm build` in both to build their respective build processes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're using. In a react app `npm start` actually does `npm run start` but npm have allowed a shorthand version.

If you look in your package.json you'll see a `scripts` parameter that has all the things you can run using `npm run [command]`. You can define your own ones in there as well.

To answer your first question. The `start` and `build` commands are usually defined by webpack.

`start` is usually used to serve your app locally. So you can go to `localhost` and see it running.

`build` is used to compile your app into a folder, usually called dist/, into a flat html/CSS/JavaScript website so you can put the files onto a production server.