# Do the React start script run also a build?

Tags: reactjs, build

Hello I have a simple question, I think, but I didn’t find an answer.

I know that React uses JSX and so, because of the browser knows only Vanilla JS, the code to be run should be compiled. When I run `yarn build`, the code will be minified ad compiled and the resulting files are in a `build` folder. Then, If I want to deploy the site for example using Netlify, I need to setup the build command. Basically Netlify build the apps, save the built files somewhere and serve these files.

What I am asking now is how the `start` command works. In that case, how does the browser can read the React files? Everytime I run `yarn start` the `start` script run also a build in watch mode or something like this?

(i'm supposing I'm using create-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

`start` command simply compiles all your code to view and edit locally. We can say that we have created a local build. But that is just for our understanding.

Whereas `build` command creates a folder to be served online on a server to be viewed (only) on internet.

Both commands have a huge difference.This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805483/npm-basics-clarification-differences-between-npm-start-and-npm-build) can help you more.
Happy Coding:-)

Comment: Thank you!  and where can I find the `local build`?

Comment: Just use the command - npx serve, Using serve, our app will start up on a different development port instead of 3000.

Comment: No there is no build folder in `npm start` . It just creates local url for development.

Comment: npx serve is commonly used to quickly test a production build of your application locally.

Answer (score 1):

As Per your question, It depends on your script, by default NO.

These are all custom script, you can find the definition in package.json file. Normally start is for starting the development build, build is for making the production build.

```
For Example - 

**"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"lint": "eslint ./src",
"lint:fix": "eslint ./src --fix",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"test:coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll=false",
"build": "rollup -c",**
```

Comment: exactly, as you said, "start is for starting the development build" so a build is made. no?

Comment: By default, when you run npm start, it doesn't perform a production build. Instead, it compiles your React code on-the-fly using a development server, and it sets up hot reloading, so any changes you make to your code will automatically reflect in the running application without the need to manually restart the server or refresh the page.